# join multiple table(4 tables) with different conditions

Tags: join, left-join, teradata

I am new to `teradata` not only teradata, new to database queries side.

In my application we are using `teradata` for backend to store business data. I have bunch of `tables` in my database names are `d1,d2,d3,d4....`. I want to fetch combined data from 4 tables names are `d1,d2,d3,d4` based on 3 or 4 conditions. For this I want to use `joins` but I don't know which join am I need to use. Regarding this I written following code as per my assumption.

```
SELECT b.businessID,
  b.location,
  b.role,
  r.roleID,
  r.role,
  c.code,
  c.name
FROM Business b
JOIN Account r
ON b.role=r.role
JOIN country c
ON c.id           =b.businessID
WHERE b.location <> bangalore
```

can anyone suggest me with your sample codes.

Thanks.

Comment: please format the code

Answer (score 1):

`WHERE b.location <> 'bangalore'`

`bangalore` should be embedded in single quotes, else will be treated as column name and would fail with `Invalid Identifier`